# Why does this Java program calculate incorrectly

Tags: java

The following program is part of a larger program demonstrating how public and private keys work but it gives the wrong answer. It gives a result of 123.0 but if you do the calculation in Windows Calculator or in a Python version it gives a result of 99

```java
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int eData = 176;
        int PK = 23;
        int N = 187;
        double x = Math.pow(eData, PK);
        double unenData = x % N;
        System.out.println ("Decrypted data :");
        System.out.println (unenData);
    }
}
```

The program gives a result of 12.0, I was expecting the result of 99.
Thanks in advance for your help.